# Use pragma to disable a warning if implemented

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings

Clang recently implemented an annoying warning. If I disable it using `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored`, then older Clang versions will emit an "unknown warning group" warning.

Is there some way to test whether a warning is implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent versions of Clang implement the `__has_warning` feature-check macro. Since Clang emulates GCC (not vice-versa) with only one pool of warning flags, it's reasonable to code against GCC using feature-check introspection:

```
#if __GNUC__ && defined( __has_warning )
#   if __has_warning( "-Wwhatever" )
#       define SUPPRESSING
#       pragma GCC diagnostic push
#       pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwhatever"
#   endif
#endif

// Code that trips warning

#ifdef SUPPRESSING
#   undef SUPPRESSING
#   pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif
```

This is a bit of cumbersome copypasta. It can be avoided using an inclusion file, like this:

```
#define SUPPRESS_WARNING "-Wwhatever"
#include "suppress_warning.h"

// Code that trips warning

#include "unsuppress_warning.h"
```

`suppress_warning.h` is a bit tricky, because `__has_warning` and `#pragma` do not accept macros as arguments. So, get it from [Github](https://github.com/potswa/suppress_warning) or this [Wandbox demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5wMC29SXQPOrwp6w).

Comment: @NathanOliver `defined( __has_warning )` will evaluate to `false` on such compilers.

Comment: Just saw that.  comment retracted

Comment: @NathanOliver It's alright :) I'll just leave my response as a talisman against the concern being raised again.

Comment: One can also use conditionally compiled (depending on the compiler) macro with  "_Pragma" inside it to wrap the different push warning syntax. Then one can use PUSH_WARNING("-Wwhatever") instead of the #include and it works on all compilers.